# PHP CURL : Loop until HTTP 200 Response is received

Tags: php, curl

I'm sending a Post Data to a website, but that website return's 502 Bad Gateway most of the time. I want to send Post data every second until that Website accepts my Post Request.

```
<?php
$postData = "";
$req = curl_init("example.com");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"\_");
$result = curl_exec($req);

echo "Status code: ".curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)."\\n";
echo "Response body: ".$result."\\n";
curl_close($req);
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried Posting Data to that website. but my script executed only once, i want to run my script in a loop

Comment: then create a loop calling the curl block please. (**However**, if I were the webmaster of the site and notice such traffic I will immediately block it)

Comment: @KenLee Thanks but actually new to PHP, can you please guide how can Loop Curl, using above code?

Comment: There are many ways to repeat the curl . See my suggested method for one of the ways

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to repeat doing the curl every n seconds. You may loop over the curl block with **sleep**, or simply use HTML refresh to do the job.

For sleep, you may refer to the following documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.sleep.php

Option 1: For HTML way, you may simply add a line (say to re-run the curl script every 5 seconds):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
```

PHP code can be:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

<?php
$postData = "";
$req = curl_init("example.com");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"\_");
$result = curl_exec($req);

echo "Status code: ".curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)."\\n";
echo "Response body: ".$result."\\n";
curl_close($req);
?>
```

Option 2:
For PHP way (or command mode), please do things thru sleep like this:

```
<?php

$success=0;

while ($success==0){

// your original curl

$postData = "";
$req = curl_init("example.com");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"\_");
$result = curl_exec($req);

echo "Status code: ".curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)."\\n";

if ( curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) =="200" ){
$success=1; 
}

echo "Response body: ".$result."\\n";
curl_close($req);

// end curl


     // wait for 10 seconds before the next iteration
        sleep(10); 
     // end wait.
}
?>
```

However (for option 2), please set the php script execution timeout to be long enough for your need. Say by amending the php.ini , or add the following to the top of your PHP:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5000); //5000 seconds
```

Comment: Mate, I will be using PHP through command line, not on browser. So, this method won't ork for me. Please Suggest me another method.

Comment: I see, please try option 2 above

Comment: Thanks Mate. And sorry, I am new to Stackoverflow and I am not able to Upvote your answer. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: You got a typo near `curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(");`

Comment: +1 for remember to set the php script execution timeout.  If you add in the top of the code it will be perfect answer (imo).

Comment: Thank You all. I got another problem. Like I need to post a value to the website but that website won't accept it until the value on their website and mine value matches. If I post and Reissue that value as repeater it causes 502 Error on that website. Is there any way that I Issue a single Post Request to do my task?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to repeat your `curl_exec` call until `CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE` is 200.

```
$postData = "";
$req = curl_init("example.com");
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(''));
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_COOKIE,'\_');

do {
    $result = curl_exec($req);
    $responseCode = curl_getinfo($req, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);

    echo "Status code: $responseCode\n";
    echo "Response body: $result\n";

    // keep in mind that sleep returns 0 on success,
    // that would evaluate to false without strict comparison
} while ($responseCode !== 200 && sleep(1) !== false);

curl_close($req);
```

Comment: The loop could be improved: as it is written, it will always wait 1 second more than necessary.

Comment: You are correct. Now it should only sleep if `$responseCode !== 200`. Tried to avoid duplicating comparison in the loop and an early break.

Comment: Thank You all. I got another problem. Like I need to post a value to the website but that website won't accept it until the value on their website and mine value matches. If I post and Reissue that value as repeater it causes 502 Error on that website. Is there any way that I Issue a single Post Request to do my task?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$processCompleted = false;
$interval = 5; //5 seconds
$request = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:'.$token));

while(!$processCompleted) {
    
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    // Check HTTP status code
    if (!curl_errno($response)) {
        switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($request , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
        case 200:  # OK
            ...//do your stuff
            break;
        default:
            sleep($interval);
        }
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```